# Loop troubles in C#

Tags: c#

I seem to having a problem where I need an integer from a loop for the loop condition, here's the code:

```
do {
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("What file would you like to test?");
    Console.WriteLine("1. Royal Flush");
    Console.WriteLine("2. Straight Flush");
    Console.WriteLine("3. Four of a Kind");
    Console.WriteLine("4. Full House");
    Console.WriteLine("5. Flush");
    Console.WriteLine("6. Straight");
    Console.WriteLine("7. Three of a Kind");
    Console.WriteLine("8. Two Pair");
    Console.WriteLine("9. Pair");
    Console.WriteLine("10. Exit");
    choiceInt = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
} while (choiceInt < 10 || choiceInt > 0);
```

I need the choiceInt for the condition of the loop, to get this to work at the moment i have to let it loop through once before it gets a value,

Comment: Why do you need to have a loop? Why not just print each option then the read and using `switch` to do something with the value.

Comment: It loops to test poker hands from files, this is just a section of code, i have switches below this code for other things, but I just posted the code I need help with.

Comment: unrelated, but also look into int.TryParse() - it will save you from an exception with Convert.ToInt32()

Comment: Can I confirm that you are trying to repeat the loop for any value from `1` to `9`, but exit on any other value, but explicitly on `10`?

Answer (score 1):

You have your `>` and `<` wrong: you want a condition that evaluates to `true` when the choice is *wrong* (hence the loop should continue asking the user for input). Since `do` / `while` exits when the condition turns `false`, you can be sure that after exiting the loop `choiceInt` is in the valid range.

The condition should look like this:

```
do {
    ...
} (choiceInt < 0 || choiceInt > 10);
//    ^^^^              ^^^^
//  negative          above ten
```

Comment: @JasonJarrett The current code exits the loop when `10` is entered, because assigning `10` to `choiceInt` turns *continuation condition* to `false`.

Answer (score -1):

This will work for you:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string consoleInput;
        ShowOptions();         

        do
        {
            consoleInput = Console.ReadLine();
            if (consoleInput == "10")
                Environment.Exit(0);

            DoSomething();
            ShowOptions();

        } while (consoleInput != null && consoleInput != "10");
    }

    private static void ShowOptions()
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("What file would you like to test?");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Royal Flush");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Straight Flush");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Four of a Kind");
        Console.WriteLine("4. Full House");
        Console.WriteLine("5. Flush");
        Console.WriteLine("6. Straight");
        Console.WriteLine("7. Three of a Kind");
        Console.WriteLine("8. Two Pair");
        Console.WriteLine("9. Pair");
        Console.WriteLine("10. Exit");
    }

    private static void DoSomething() { Console.WriteLine("I am doing something!"); }
```

Answer (score -1):

I would be inclined to try an tidy up the code to make it more generic. Try doing this:

```
var options = new []
{
    new { option = 1, text = "Royal Flush" },
    new { option = 2, text = "Straight Flush" },
    new { option = 3, text = "Four of a Kind" },
    new { option = 4, text = "Full House" },
    new { option = 5, text = "Flush" },
    new { option = 6, text = "Straight" },
    new { option = 7, text = "Three of a Kind" },
    new { option = 8, text = "Two Pair" },
    new { option = 9, text = "Pair" },
    new { option = 10, text = "Exit" },
};

string choice;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("What file would you like to test?");
    Console.WriteLine(
        String.Join(
            Environment.NewLine,
            options.Select(o => String.Format("{0}. {1}", o.option, o.text))));
    choice = Console.ReadLine();
} while (options.Take(9).Any(o => o.option.ToString() == choice));
```

Comment: you are providing 10 as an option, so even when the user will select 10 your loop goes on.

Comment: @Nikita - No, when you enter `10` the loop exits. I tested the code before posting.

Comment: Did you check for 1 to 9 also? Options array contains 1 to 10 , when choice=10(entered by the user) options.Any() condition returns true, !options.Any() will be false, it exits. But, for 1 to 9 also it exits for the same reason as above.Its not just the condition that is wrong,also my 1st comment holds when you will modify.

Comment: @Nikita - I have checked. For all correct input values (`1` to `10`) it correctly exits. For all other values it loops.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. it should display the option & let the user select until the user exits. so for 1 to 9 it should run the loop & for 10 it should come out of the loop.

Comment: @Nikita - Ah, I see. I think I was thrown by dasblinkenlight's answer. He's using the same logic that my answer was using. I'll update.